# What is the meaning of screened potential?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, material-science, fluid-statics

I keep reading that it is supposed to account for the particle-medium interactions, but why do we need another potential besides the Coulomb one that includes the interaction between every particle in the system?

Answer (score 1):

You are right in saying that the Coulomb potential includes the interaction between every particle in the system. However, screened potentials are not intended as *another potential*. They efficiently deal with the screening effects naturally present in oppositely charged multi-component Coulomb systems.

The main Physics behind screened potentials is the fact that any pair of charged particles in a system of that kind interact directly via the Coulomb interaction and indirectly through the interaction with the other charges present in the medium. The resulting effect of these two interactions can be treated at different levels of accuracy through effective interactions of increasing accuracy, where a direct screened interaction between charges replaces the effect of the "solvent" charges.

Depending on the system, one may have screened interactions between ions due to the presence of other ions and electrons (for example, the case of screened interactions in metallic systems) or due to the presence of oppositely charged ions (the case of electrolytic solutions).

I am speaking of different screened interactions because, within the general scheme, it is possible to derive interactions at different levels of approximation.

The above considerations are quite general. More specific information would require to focus on a particular physical system.

Comment: But then youd be averaging the coulomb interaction with the ions in a mean field screened potential?

Comment: @RichHardFineMan In principle, screened potential does not coincide with the usual mean field approximation. Correlations may appear at some approximate level. The important point is that the particles responsible for the screening may always be considered at their thermodynamic equilibrium.

Answer (score 0):

> why do we need another potential besides the Coulomb one that includes the interaction between every particle in the system?

The problem is that we can not solve the problem if we include all the Coulomb interactions between all the electrons and nuclei in the system explicitly. In a solid state system like a macroscopic die of aluminum there are on the order of $10^{23}$ electrons and nuclei. We simply can not solve such a problem (we usually can not even solve the *three* body problem exactly, so we certainly can't solve the $10^{23}$-body problem exactly).

We can make a very rough first attempt at solving the many-body problem with [the *independent electron approximation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_electron_approximation) (see, e.g., [Ashcroft and Mermin](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/8131500527) at Chapter 1). In such an approximation we can think of independent electrons as moving in a [mean field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean-field_theory) of all the other electrons and ions. These hypothetical independent electrons would not see the bare Coulomb potential of the nuclei, rather they would see a screened Coulomb potential.

One can go further and think about how the potential seen by independent electrons must change to self-consistently arrive at certain "exact" quantities such as the ground state density. These type of "screened" or "mean" field theories are called [density functional theories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Density_functional_theory). They can be quite good at describing materials that do not have "strong correlations." But, in general, the many-body problem is difficult when we have to understand the detailed effects of electron-electron interactions and often we fall back to toy models like [the Hubbard model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hubbard_model).

Comment: So that would qualify as a screened potential? In a N+1 particles system, i think its common to express the interaction with the other N particles in terms of the particle density. Is that a screened potential?

Comment: The "screening" means the effects of all the other particles. A screened potential might look something like $Ze^{-r/\lambda}/r$ as opposed to $Z/r$. The exact form of the screening and the parameter (e.g., the $\lambda$ in my screened example) are coming from the approximation where you try to get rid of the complexity of the full many-body system and reduce everything down to an effective one-electron potential...

Comment: You can also think of this in terms of a dielectric constant. You have something like $v_{sc} = \epsilon v_{coulomb}$. So, like, in momentum space you have $v_{coulomb} = 4\pi Z/q^2$, but maybe you have $\epsilon = \frac{\epsilon_0 q^2}{q^2 + 1/\lambda^2}$, so you get back the same screened potential I gave as an example earlier. The hard part is calculating $\epsilon(q,\omega)$ from the many-body theory.

Comment: ok, i think i understand. thank you :)